# Contextual type 'NSObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a method that resets the password of a user, and I'm making this request asynchronously. The line that throws this error is the following:

```
authController.resetPasswordAsyncWithEmail(["email": email]) { (success, context, _, error) -> Void in
...
```

"Contextual type 'NSObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal"

The resetPasswithAsyncWithEmail is as follows:

```
- (void) resetPasswordAsyncWithEmail:(NSObject*) email
            completionBlock:(CompletedPostResetPassword) onCompleted
{
    ....
}
```

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Had to change the lingo of the method a bit and cast the dictionary as NSObject like so:

```
authController.resetPasswordAsync(withEmail: ["email": email] as NSObject!) { (success, context, _, error) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 3 right? has been seen those a lot while porting swift 2.2 code lately. Wondering what happens if you leave the swift code as before but change the objC to - (void) resetPasswordAsyncWithEmail:(id) email, id is now seen as Any from swift